# Adaptar leitor de arquivo txt

Tags: java, arquivo, arraylist, dialog, txt

Eu estava usando um método manual para pegar um arquivo txt, onde o usuário digitava o nome do arquivo e a extensão e apertava o botão, agora que substituir por um código que abre uma caixa de pesquisa para escolher o arquivo no hd.

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

E o meu código atual está assim:

```
private ArrayList<String> carregaTxt(){
    ArrayList<String> resultado = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);


String nome = nomeTXT.getText();

System.out.printf("\nConteúdo do arquivo texto:\n");
try {

  FileReader arq = new FileReader(nome);
  BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

  String linha = lerArq.readLine(); // lê a primeira linha

  while (linha != null) {
    System.out.printf("%s\n", linha);

    String[] palavrasDaLinha = linha.split(" ");

    for(String palavra : palavrasDaLinha) {

        if( palavra.trim().length() > 1 && !"".equals(palavra.trim())) {
            resultado.add(palavra);  
        }

    }

    linha = lerArq.readLine(); // lê da segunda até a última linha
  }

  arq.close();


  System.out.println("\n");
  System.out.printf("Total de palavras no arquivo: %s\n", resultado.size());

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo: %s.\n",
      e.getMessage());
}   

    return resultado;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitua a variável `nome` pelo `selectedFile`. Ex:

```
File selectedFile = null;

JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

try {
    if (selectedFile != null) {
        FileReader arq = new FileReader(selectedFile);
        BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
        //...
    }
} catch (Exception e) {} //tratar exceções...
```

A classe `FileReader` aceita tanto Objetos `File` quanto a `String` com o caminho/nome do arquivo.

Comment: Fiz o que recomendou, porém ele não encontra o selectedFile no FileReader, da como variável inexistente. Fiz algo errado?

Comment: Provavelmente porque está dentro de um `try-catch`. Você precisa inicializar o `File` fora dele. Vou incluir na resposta.